# How to capture mouseDown Events in a WebView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, webkit

I would like to handle the `mouseDown` events in the `WebView`. I subclassed the `WebView`,implemented the `mouseDown` and I came to know the `mouseDown` was redirected to `WebHTMLView`.

I have gone through the following link.

[mouseDown: not firing in WebView subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341278/mousedown-not-firing-in-webview-subclass)

From the above link I got to know, We can redirect the mouseDownEvent to Objective-C,but I did not find any solution for this. Can I have any Pointers or sample javascript to implement the same.

I tried the  hitTest method in `webview` subclass.

```
- (NSView*)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
```

Is it possible to recognize the mouseDown in the above method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following HTML and JavaScript to capture the mouseEvents and to display the position of the mouse click in the `WebView`.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function SetValues()
    {
        var s = 'X=' + window.event.clientX +  ' Y=' + window.event.clientY ;
        document.getElementById('divCoord').innerText = s;

    }  
</script>
</head>
<body id="bodyTag" onclick=SetValues()>
<div id="divCoord"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use onTouchStart Event for the same .Refer this [link to bind events on iphone](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

or use this :-

```
$('button').bind( "touchstart", function(){alert('hey'} );
```

touchstart is equivalent to mouseDown

Another Solution is to set the element's cursor to pointer and it work with jQuery live and click event .Set it in CSS.(cursor:pointer)

IN javaScript you can use :-

```
node.ontouchmove = function(e){
  if(e.touches.length == 1){ // Only deal with one finger
    var touch = e.touches[0]; // Get the information for finger #1
    var node = touch.target; // Find the node the drag started from
    node.style.position = "absolute";
    node.style.left = touch.pageX + "px";
    node.style.top = touch.pageY + "px";
  }
}
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    alert(event.touches.length);
}, false);
```

for more details refer [javascript iPhone Events](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/)

For Mac OSx See [The Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755848/javascript-events-for-gestures-in-webkit-on-mac)

Comment: corona zorro :It's not iPhone.Do you have any tips for the same  Cocoa ?

Comment: Cocoa Touch is a UI framework for building software programs to run on the iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad from Apple Inc.So,it would work on these also , its just a part of iPhone.